# Sphinx Search not returning results or errors

Tags: php, database, search, text, sphinx

I have been working with sphinxapi.php and the script works fine you can check it out [at this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DnaRmSxu). You can check out my table structure [right here](http://pastebin.com/RkXcz5gQ) and this is how my sphinx.conf file is setup:

```
# Minimal Sphinx configuration sample (clean, simple, functional)
#

#Movie Source
source movielist
{
    type            = mysql
    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = root
    sql_pass        = jetru9rU
    sql_db          = imdb
    sql_port        = 3306

    sql_query   = \
        SELECT id, title, subtitle, year_created FROM movielist

    sql_attr_string     = title
    sql_attr_string     = subtitle
    sql_attr_uint       = year_created

    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE id=$id

}
#Movie Index
index movieindex
{
    source          = movielist
    path            = /var/data/movieindex
    docinfo         = extern
    charset_type        = sbcs
}

#Realtime indexing
index movieindexrt
{
    type            = rt
    rt_mem_limit        = 32M

    path            = /var/data/movieindexrt
    charset_type        = utf-8

    rt_field        = title
    rt_field        = subtitle
}

indexer
{
    mem_limit       = 32M
}


searchd
{
    listen          = 9312
    listen          = 9306:mysql41
    log         = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
    query_log       = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
    read_timeout        = 5
    max_children        = 30
    pid_file        = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
    max_matches     = 1000
    seamless_rotate     = 1
    preopen_indexes     = 1
    unlink_old      = 1
    workers         = threads # for RT to work
    binlog_path     = /var/data
}
```

What is wrong with my .conf file that I am not seeing?

Comment: Is it working or not? In the title you say not. But in the question you say your script works fine. Which is it? Would help to explain more about the issue you have...

Answer (score 0):

Ah! You have no fields. See this page for more information:

http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=fields_and_attributes